# any downside to use latest Eclipse with my Java 8 project?

Tags: java, eclipse

The project I am working on is a Java 8 project. I haven't updated my Eclipse for years. The latest Eclipse required Java 11. I know I can point my project to Java 8. Are there any potential issues with doing so?

Comment: Nope.  Just specify "Java 8" as the target in your project settings.  That should be perfectly OK.  FYI, Eclipse has its *OWN* Java compiler, independent of the JRE you use to *RUN* Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Java used by Eclipse does NOT depend on version of Java you are using for compilation the project.

E.g. you can run Eclipse on Java11 and setup it to build the project using Java8.

There is only downside I can see: using an old version of IDE you are loosing all new fancy features.